# May IAudioClient::SetEventHandle be called only exactly once?

Tags: audio, windows-10

Here is some simplified code example to explain my question:

```
bool Signaled(HANDLE const e)
{

return WaitForSingleObject(e, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;

}

void SomeFunction()
{

HANDLE const e1 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL); // not signaled
HANDLE const e2 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL); // not signaled
HANDLE const e3 = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL); // not signaled

// let f() be a function that creates the object behind IAudioClient
// with AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE and AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_EVENTCALLBACK
// but does not call IAudioClient::SetEventHandle
IAudioClient * const a = f(); // assume success

a->SetEventHandle(e1); // initial call, returns S_OK

assert(!Signaled(e1)); // true

a->SetEventHandle(e2); // subsequent call, returns S_OK

assert(!Signaled(e1)); // true
assert(!Signaled(e2)); // true

a->SetEventHandle(e3); // subsequent call, returns S_OK

assert(!Signaled(e1)); // true
assert(!Signaled(e2)); // true
assert(!Signaled(e3)); // true 

a->Start(); // returns S_OK

assert(!Signaled(e1)); // true, as I expected
assert(!Signaled(e2)); // false!!!
assert(Signaled(e3)); // may be true or false, that's OK

}
```

To my very surprise, e2 is signaled, too. Why?

The documentation does not say that IAudioClient::SetEventHandle may be called only exactly once and then never again.

If it may be called again with a different event handle than the current one, I would expect the current one to simply be replaced by the new one. But it seems that IAudioClient somehow keeps both event handles and then signals both upon Start(). As far as I understand WASAPI and its event callback mechanism this does not make sense.

Or does IAudioClient have a list of the latest two event handles? Or is this a bug in IAudioClient? Or is the documentation incomplete?

Help is greatly appreciated. Larry Osterman, if you should happen to read this, can you explain?

Comment: Pretty doubtful that anybody has ever noticed this behavior.  The docs also don't say it will forget about a previously registered handle nor is there an error code reserved for that.  You'd need to also assert that e2 is signaled to conclude that a list is being kept.

Comment: @HansPassant Strange feature, I wonder why they bothered.  I certainly wouldn't want to rely on it.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, e2 is signaled, too.

Comment: Doing the extra work of maintaining a list is feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I agree, but how would I know about that feature? I cannot find anything about it in the docs. So I think it is reasonable to assume that a function named SetSomething() replaces what is currently set rather than add to it. And the docs say that "the event handle is signaled" and not "the event handles are signaled".

Comment: You know about it by testing the code.  Done, now you know.

Comment: @HansPassant No, I don't. I have added a third event handle in the example. And it turns out that it is not a list. e1 is now not signaled, but e2 is. That makes even less sense. What kind of feature should that be?